# displaying decimal values depending on decimal places in string.format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) for displaying validation messages. I'm trying to achieve a scenario where, if decimal is there, show `12.34`, else don't show any decimal points like, `12`.

I tried to achieve it by using type as number. My string is,

```
Please enter value between {1:N} and {2:N}. // Displays 1.00 and 2.00
Please enter value between {1:N0} and {2:N0}. // Displays 1 and 2
```

What I should do to fix this? I need comma separation depending on culture. Using `{1:G}` will not provide that.

Comment: How about `{1:G}` and `{2:G}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 0 means a digit will always be shown. Use a # to show optional digits.

```
{1:0.##}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using :G . for isntance: `Please enter value between {1:G} and {2:G}.` Or `{1:0.##}`